# Animation of a plane wave

Tags: plotting, animation

I want to animate in 3D the plane wave $\sin(\omega t+kx+\phi)$, but following the form from the documentation, I can only make $k$ or $\omega$ vary, and I want $t$ to change. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome! Please do add more info,  especially your code. Consider that the more precise and informative your question, the better your chances for good answers will be.

Comment: Thank you. There's no really much of a code. I just don't know how to use this function. There may be some proper tag for questions like this, maybe, that I should have used. I wrote this:

Animate[Plot3D[
  Sin[\[Omega]*t + k*x + \[Pi]/3], {x, -2, 2}, {t, -5, 5}], {k, -1, 
  1}]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this?:

```
wave[x_, t_, k_, ω_, ϕ_] := Sin[ω*t + k.x + ϕ];
Animate[Plot3D[wave[{x, y}, t, {1, 1}, 1, 0], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}],
 {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica session]

where `{x,y}` or `x` in the wave function definition is a 2D vector (in order to be able to draw it; in reality, `x` is a 3D vector and there would be no way to plot), `k` is the wave vector (I just used `{1, 1}` for demonstration), its magnitude is related to wavelength as $k = 2\pi/\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength, its direction relates to the direction of the wave (energy) propagation. ω is the frequency (I chose 1) and ϕ is the phase which I chose as 0.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I have been looking for. What do these numbers: t, {1, 1}, 1, 0 represent and how should this be read?

Comment: Aha, I get, it is $k$, $\omega$ and $\phi$. Whoa, I'm really a beginner.

Comment: I guess "fucked up" should mean having low plot resolution because of default `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"` chosen due to `Animate`. One might want to use explicit `PerformanceGoal->"Quality"` option for `Plot3D`.

Comment: They are very polygonal, and at the saddle points there are differently colored triangles. Animations in Wolfram demonstrations usually look much smoother. Sorry for my use of imprecise and non-academic "fucked up".

Comment: PerformanceGoal -> "Quality" did the job, kinda. Thank you.

Comment: Since this I am posting a link, I cannot call this an answer. Dan Russel at Penn State has a site (http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos.html) devoted to acoustics animations with some very informative Mathematica generated animations, including plane waves showing the particle dynamics involved.